# armature disappears when importing a skinned character in obj, format?

Tags: armature

[image]armature present before importing

[[image: enter image description [1]][image: armature before importing[![][1]][1]]

Comment: Can you upoload a screenshot or the file of your blend? I can't focus your problem

Comment: I have now tried to import a different rigged character but the armature gets missing in the importing process

Comment: i repeat please upload your file. We can't help you. Your question is not focues enought

Comment: the problem is obvious from the images I have now added and the thus the  question more focused

Answer (score 3):

Obj format that supports only geometry and does not support rigs or animations.

> The OBJ file format is a simple data-format that represents 3D geometry alone — namely, the position of each vertex, the UV position of each texture coordinate vertex, vertex normals, and the faces that make each polygon defined as a list of vertices, and texture vertices. -wikipedia

For animations you should use some other format. Fbx for example is supported by most 3d software and popular game engines Unity and Unreal.

Comment: Animation can be exported... with 1 obj per frame (export option)

Comment: It can, but that is blender-specific behaviour not defined in .obj specification and not universally supported.

Comment: when I tried importing in Fbx. format I got the bones but not the controllers with it. how can I get the controllers for the character?

Comment: I don't know what kind of controllers you are talking about, but if you mean stuff like constraints you are out of luck as those are blender's own system and cannot be exported any way i'm aware of. Simple parent-child relationships should be exported just fine.

Comment: @Rawcal  When I tried generating the mesh it didn`t work any suggestions on how to generate that?